# Injectivity of the function $x||x||$ on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let ,  $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ be a function defined by $f(x)=x||x||^2$ for $x\in \mathbb R^n$.  Then , which are correct ?

(A) $f$ is one-one.

(B) $f$ has an inverse.

Here $f$ is not a linear map , so we can't use to find $ker(f)=0$.
Again from the formal definition of **one-one** we can't find..How I can conclude about injectivity ? I know  $f$ is injective if and only if inverse always exists in this case.

Comment: shouldn't it be $f$ is *bijective* iff $f$ has an inverse?

Comment: @ElliotG depends how you define the domain of the inverse

Comment: @  Elliot G) What? Cite an example.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 for example, $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = e^x$ doesn't have an inverse $f^{-1}: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bijection_iff_Left_and_Right_Inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that

- $f(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$
- $\|f(x)\| = \|x\|^3$
- $f(x)/\|f(x)\| = x/\|x\|$ (for $x \neq 0$)

That is enough to deduce injectivity.

Comment: Not clear...More detail?

Comment: If $f(x) = f(y)$, you need to show that $x = y$.  These pieces of information are enough to do so.

Comment: From your last point , $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $\frac{x||f(x)||}{||x||}=\frac{y||f(y)||}{||y||}$. Then ?

Comment: How about, $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $\|x\| = \|y\|$ and $x/\|x\| = y/\|y\|$

Answer (score 1):

$y=x\Vert x \Vert^2$ implies $\Vert y\Vert=\Vert x\Vert^3$.

$g(y):=y / \Vert y\Vert^\frac{2}{3}$ is the inverse and is defined on $y\neq o$

So you have
$f^{-1}(y)=g(y)$, if $y\neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Your first statement alone is not enough to deduce injectivity.

Comment: define $g(0):=0$

Comment: it is one-to-one